# Facebook на днях изменили JavaScript SDK авторизацию что ли?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-api

Добрый вечер.

Не уверен по адресу ли вопрос, но.. появилась проблема с авторизацией через facebook javascript sdk.

До сегодняшнего дня пользовался реализацией авторизации от [этого парня](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/), скрипт у него сделан понятно и по документации. Просто с украшениями (текст в кнопочках меняется и по мелочи). Все было хорошо, но сегодня заметил что появилась проблема при разлогинивании. Вот можете даже у него в [примере](http://thinkdiff.net/demo/newfbconnect1/jssdkouth2.html) посмотреть. Сначала логинитесь, потом жмете logout, затем снова пытаетесь залогинится. Не получиться, т.к. разлогинивание то и не произошло полностью. Кнопка якобы залипает. При нажатии на нее файрбаг выдаёт такое: FB.logout() called without an access token. Т.е. они походу прикрутили еще и на выход токен. Ктото знает как его в скрипт добавить?  Или что делать вообще?

```
button.onclick = function() {
    FB.logout(function(response) {    //вот сюда
        logout(response);   //на эту ф-цию не обращайте внимание
    });
};
```

Comment: Или может ктото поделится своим куском кода авторизации на фейсбуке?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема была в `FB.event.subscribe`.

Поменял `auth.statusChange` на другого 'слушателя' - `auth.authResponseChange`, теперь всё как нужно)